# accessing information in a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector

I currently have a vector of pointers, how would I `cout` the information at a particular pointer in the vector?

I am looking at how to deference the address stored in the vector.

Comment: Just like how you dereference anything else. Please post the code that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<MyType*> addressList;
cout<<(*(addresssList[i])).Data ; //assuming Data is the content you want to output and you would like to output the content addressed by the `ith` element.
```

Comment: the "MyType" for me is a Class.
the data that I was trying to access was a private variable. I defined a member function to return the information that I want, but my compiler says  i need the this pointer "->". why is that

Comment: @Panda: If X is a class with some member function f(), and you have X * pX, then to call f() a valid syntax is pX->f(). (An alternative could be (*pX).f()).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int*> ints;
for ( auto cur = ints.begin(); cur != ints.end(); ++cur)
{
     std::cout << (*(*cur)) << "\n";
}
```